# Magento 2.2 - Mage-Report Exposed Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, security, magento2.2.3, security-patch

Magento 2.2.3
I have scan the website in Mage Report, How to solve Exposed Api issue. What magento2 patch for this instead to upgrade version.

[image]

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/anonymous-api-security.html this content may be hlep